# Can't get OpenCV up'n'running in Raspberry Pi, what should I do? (details in the description)

Tags: opencv, python-3, raspberry-pi-desktop

I followed the whole tutorial (https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-opencv-python-on-raspberry-pi/) line by line, but at the end when I imported the OpenCV library in Python CLI, it gave this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import * ImportError: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am new to Raspi and can't figure out what the error is. Thanks for helping, in advance. :)

Comment: Are you running raspberry-pi-desktop OR Raspbian?

Comment: Please note that `raspberry-pi-desktop` only runs on a PC or Mac. It does not run on a Raspberry Pi. There you have to use Raspbian.